# Generate a random matrix in R which the sum of each rows is equal to 1

Tags: r

I want to generate a matrix(4 rows and 30 columns) in R software, with random elements, by range of the elements between 0 and 1, which the sum of each rows equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick `n` numbers in [0,1] which sum to 1 you are in effect picking `n-1` breakpoints. You can pick the breakpoints and then work backwards to the numbers:

```
rand.sum <- function(n){
  x <- sort(runif(n-1))
  c(x,1) - c(0,x)
}
```

And then

```
t(replicate(4,rand.sum(30)))
```

will be a 4x30 matrix of random numbers where eaxch row sums to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on the softmax (multinomial logit) transform.

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(4 * 30), nrow=30)
prob <- exp(m)/rowSums(exp(m))

rowSums(prob)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

all(prob > 0 & prob < 1)
#[1] TRUE
```